# View does not displayed

Tags: eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have made Hello World RCP application and got the following class structure:

```
ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.java 
ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java
ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java
Application.java
Perspective.java
```

Further I tried to add some view to the perspective.

Add extension point to my plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
     class="first.rcp.application.MainView"
     id="first.rcp.application.MainView"
     name="name"
     restorable="true">
  </view>
</extension>
```

and created class MainView.java.

Add additional code to Perspective.createInitialLayout():

```
layout.addStandaloneView(MainView.ID, true, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, layout.getEditorArea());
IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();
try {
   activePage.showView(MainView.ID);
} catch (PartInitException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But view does not displayed.

I set breakpoint into Perspective.createInitialLayout() and found that it is not performed.

I tried to add showPerspective() method to ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor() and set PERSPECTIVE_ID in ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor to the id of my perspective.

But the code into Perspective.createInitialLayout() still not performed.

Which point it should be called from?

Eclipse IDE have Java perspective with number of views opened by default. I.e. createInitialLayout() of the Java perspective is called during launching of eclipse IDE. How is it implemented? May be there are some configuration file?

My perspective declaration is:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
  <perspective 
      name="RCP Perspective"
      class="first.rcp.application.Perspective"
      id="first.rcp.application.Perspective">
  </perspective>
</extension>
```

The code in ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() is:

```
public String getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() {
   return PERSPECTIVE_ID;
}

private static final String PERSPECTIVE_ID = "first.rcp.application.Perspective";
```

Comment: What is your `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives` declaration in the plugin.xml? What is your `getInitialWindowPerspectiveId` code in the application workbench advisor? Are you starting Eclipse with the -clean option to make sure your changes are picked up?

Comment: Also note that calling `showView` in the perspective factory is incorrect and will give errors. The views you define in the factory will be displayed automatically.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your answer. I removed showView and start application with the -clean option. But view still does not displayed. I have edited initial post and add the declaration of perspective in the plugin.xml and getInitialPerspectiveId code.

Comment: My eclipse version is  Luna SR2 (4.4.2).

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong but there are lots of small things that have to be exactly correct. Eclipse can actually generate an example RCP doing exactly this - go through the New Plug-in Project wizard, make sure 'would you like to create a rich client application' is set to Yes, and select 'RCP 3.x application with a view' on the Available Templates page.

Comment: @greg-449 I have tried it exactly the way you wrote and got an empty window again. Also I tried it on Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and got many errors, such as "org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module" or "Application could not be found in the registry", - the application even not start on eclipse neon.

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in Neon.3 which means you need to change the configuration for the application. Open Run > Run Configurations... find the application in the 'Eclipse Application' section. Look at the 'Plug-ins' tab and select everything in the Target Platform section.

Comment: This works for me. All I can think of is to start the app with -clean and -clearPersistedState in the Arguments

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your help. I noticed, that 'Generate an activator, a Java class that controls the plug-in lifecycle' is not checked on the New Plug-in Project wizard. When I checked it and create project, the view became visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution №1.**

1. Go through the New Plug-in project wizard, make sure 'would you like to create a rich client application' is set to Yes, make sure **'Generate an activator, a Java class that controls the plug-in lifecycle'** is cheked and select 'Hello RCP' on the Available Template page.
2. Go to MANIFEST.MF, Extensions. Add new extension 'org.eclipse.ui.views', add an appropriate class.
3. Add new extension 'org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions' with the view. Specify view id to the id of the previously created view.

**Solution №2.**

Go through the New Plug-in project wizard, make sure 'would you like to create a rich client application' is set to Yes, make sure 'Generate an activator, a Java class that controls the plug-in lifecycle' is cheked and select 'RCP application with a view' on the Available Template page.